# Restore Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue, restore

I wanted to remove Ubuntu and get back to Windows. I had both Windows and Ubuntu running on my system. To remove Ubuntu I just deleted the partition and unmounted the live CD and now I am getting this error saying "error:no such partition. " What should I do to get my Windows 7 back!!?!?!

Comment: @Avinash Raj - can you please give the procedure cause I am hooked with screen which gives the above mentioned error and further needs some command...

Comment: @user252654 did you try boot-repair as given in the above link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore the bootmgr configuration. 
Use a Windows installation disc and then choose **Repair my computer** in the installation screen.
Access the command prompt and use this to restore the initialization:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

This will scan your computer and reconfigure the boot system.

Comment: I dont have a windows installation disk and need to restore my system urgently please help!!!!Now my screen reads as follows.. 'grub rescue>(cursor to type some command)'

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are desperate, you could boot off the Ubuntu disk you originally used, then follow [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to install boot-repair in your Live Ubuntu, running off the disk.

Once you have that, I'm sure it will install Grub again and give you the option of booting from your Windows partition.  Once you have finished the above guide you should have a booting Windows installation, albeit with a Grub page that pops up at the start of the boot, as you had with Ubuntu.

At least that will get you going, and there is no issue running Grub just with Windows.